# Google map gray screen

Tags: android, google-maps

On some devices map is right, but on the some devices gray screen shows instead the map

[image]

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                mapFragment = (MapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map_container);
                if (mapFragment == null) {
                    mapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
                    Log.d("CHECK_SPEED", "replace");
                    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map_container, mapFragment)
                            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out, R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out)
                            .commit();
                    setupGoogleMap();
                }
```

Comment: Is there GoogleMaps app on the device which shows the gray screen?

Comment: Were you able to digitally sign your app with the right certificate? As mentioned in [Sign Your App](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html), Android apps requires that all APKs be digitally signed with a certificate. It could either be a debug certificate or a release certificate.

Comment: @Teyam, On some devisec map is showing right way. Are you sure, than in this case does problem may be in the wrong certificate?

Comment: There can actually be many reasons which can cause problems when using Google Maps Android API and I can say digitally signing your app can be one since digital certificate is required as stated in Google Maps documentation - [Get API Key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup), "All Android apps are signed with a digital certificate for which you hold the private key."